# Search multiple columns - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, conditional-statements

I am currently writing a search method for my rails applications, and at the moment it works fine. I have the following in my game.rb:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['game_name LIKE ? OR genre LIKE ? OR console LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "#{search}", "#{search}"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

Now that searches fine, but my problem is that if there is a record in game_name that has the word 'playstation' in it, it will finish the search there. It only returns that record, rather than all games that have 'playstation' stored in console. Now I understand this is because I have 'OR' in my conditions, but I don't know an alternative. 'AND' requires all the conditions to match or none return at all. What is an alternative I can use to AND and OR? Help would be much appreciated.

If there is a solution that has separate search boxes and entries, then that would be fine, I don't necessarily require the search to find it all based on one search form.

Comment: May be a solution for you is to use a gem for what you want like https://github.com/ernie/meta_where

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your SQL looks good to me for what you are trying to do.  An OR clause will return all records that match in column1, column2, or column3.  It doesn't stop at the first match.  I do see an issue with your parameters in that the first you are using LIKE with % but in the second two you aren't, maybe that is where your issue is coming from.

Should this be your find (% around second and third search)?

```
find(:all, :conditions => ['game_name LIKE ? OR genre LIKE ? OR console LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
```

or better use DRY version (above will not work for Rails 4.2+):

```
Item.where('game_name LIKE :search OR genre LIKE :search OR console LIKE :search', search: "%#{search}%")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff, I put the % around the second and third search and it worked fine, didn't even notice that missing. Cheers for all the help.

Comment: @items = Item.where('game_name LIKE :search OR genre LIKE :search OR console LIKE :search', search: "%#{search}%").order(:name)

Answer (score 24):

What if you have 15 columns to search then you will repeat key 15 times. Instead of repeating key 15 times in query you can write like this:

```
key = "%#{search}%"

@items = Item.where('game_name LIKE :search OR genre LIKE :search OR console LIKE :search', search: key).order(:name)
```

It will give you same result.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I think this is a little bit of a cleaner solution. This allows you to add/remove columns more easily.

```
key = "%#{search}%"
columns = %w{game_name genre console}
@items = Item.where(
  columns
    .map {|c| "#{c} like :search" }
    .join(' OR '),
  search: key
)
```

Comment: Same answers but this one definitely reads better. Performance would take a hit though, wouldn't it? In all answers it's comparing a key to multiple columns, the more columns you have to look the longer it will take. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: @Breno - The only other way I can think of is to concatenate all the fields and then search that new field.     
fields = :name, :address_1, :address_2
Item.where("concat_ws(' ', #{fields.join(',')}) LIKE ?", "%#{key}%")

Answer (score 8):

A more generic solution for searching in all fields of the model would be like this

```
def search_in_all_fields model, text
  model.where(
    model.column_names
      .map {|field| "#{field} like '%#{text}%'" }
      .join(" or ")
  )
end
```

Or better as a scope in the model itself

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :search_in_all_fields, ->(text){
    where(
      column_names
        .map {|field| "#{field} like '%#{text}%'" }
        .join(" or ")
    )
  }
end
```

You would just need to call it like this

```
Model.search_in_all_fields "test"
```

Before you start.., no, sql injection would probably not work here but still better and shorter

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :search_all_fields, ->(text){
    where("#{column_names.join(' || ')} like ?", "%#{text}%")
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a more efficient solution if you want to search an array of columns as I do.

First and most importantly you can add a private function to your model that creates a query template:

```
def self.multiple_columns_like_query(array)
  array.reduce('') { |memo, x|  #
    unless memo == ''           #
      memo += ' or '            #  This is the
    end                         #  
    memo += "#{x} like :q"      #  core part
  }                             #
end
```

Than you can use the function in your search function:

```
def self.search(query)
  if fields = self.searched_fields && query
    where multiple_like_query(fields), q: "%#{query}%"
  end
end
```

Here you should also define `self.searched_fields` as an array of field names.